# 4 NSarray's in to pickerview

Tags: ios, nsarray, phone-call

how can i get 4 nsarrays into  1 pickerviewer
each array has 4 names in them.
so let say i have this:

Array1: Alex

- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx

Array2: Andrew

- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx

Array3: Sam

- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx

Array4: Rick

- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx
- Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx

and now when i pull down the pickerviewer i want to see only the names alex, andrew, sam and rick in that pickerviewer.

and when i select a name (alex) i want to have 4 buttons that are changed in to the value of the numbers so when you tap the button you can call them.

can someone help me with this issue.

i am a bit brain frozen at this moment:S

Answer (score 1):

Add them to a dictionary :

```
self.dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //Obviously create a property first:

[dict setObject:array1 forKey:@"Alex"];
//etc .....
```

Then your picker delegates would look like:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.dict allKeys] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.dict allKeys][row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *person = [dict allKeys][row];
    NSArray *personDetails = [dict objectForKey:person];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you want to use UIPickerView ? If you aren't using more then 1 component then you can use UITableView. Each cell will contain only the name as you want (with method cellForRow:), and when you'll select it (didSelectRow:) it will show the former 4 buttons of that cell, which were hidden by now. when you type on another cell, the former one come back to its default state (the buttons are hidden), and of course if you tap one of the unhidden buttons you dial to the wanted number.

Making sense ?

Comment: yes make sense i have put it in a table view now and when i select a name i get pushed to a new DetailviewController i just made and there it shows the picture and the name and the for buttons i created.

Answer (score 0):

Form what I can understand is you need to have an array with dictionaries

```
NSMutableArray *superArray = [NSMutableArray array]; //superArray should be declared in the interface

NSArray *setNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alex",@"Andrew",@"Sam",Rick,nil];

NSArray *alexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx",@"Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx",nil];
NSArray *andrewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx",@"Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx",nil];
NSArray *samArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx",@"Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx",nil];
NSArray *rickArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx",@"Tel nr:xxxxxxxxxx",nil];

NSArray *totalArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:alexArray,andrewArray,samArray,rickArray,nil];


for (int i=0 ; i < [setNames count] ; i++){
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:[setNames objectAtIndex:i],@"setName",[totalArray objectAtIndex:i],@"telephoneArray" ,nil];

[superArray addObject:dictionary];

}
```

Now you have all data stored in the way you would need it

for pickerView delegates
set numberOfRowsInCOmponent to be `[superArray count];`

titleForRowInComponent to be `[superArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"setName"];`

Further on selecting any particular name from pickerView

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
// get the array of the selected setName
//Eg: After selecting Sam in pickerView

NSArray *selectedNamesTelephoneArray = [superArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"telephoneArray"];

NSLog(@"the selected ones telephone numbers are %@",selectedNamesTelephoneArray);
}
```